# ui routing not rendering with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, templates, render, angular-ui-router

I've been going crazy with this problem. I'm building an app which has rails back end with angularjs front end. This tutorial is telling me to use ui routing to render partial templates. As I've done some tests everything seems to be working fine except for the routing. If someone can find the bug in this code please let me know. i'm fresh to javascript at all and struggling to find the issue.

The tutorial I'm following is this one. https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/

application.html.erb

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FlapperNews</title>
  <!--<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
<div class="row">


    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// templateUrl: '/assets/templates/_home.html',

angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
    //Provider
    .config([
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: '_home.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                            return posts.getAll();
                        }]
                    }
                })
                .state('posts', {
                    url: '/posts/{id}',
                    templateUrl: '_posts.html',
                    controller: 'PostsCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                            return posts.getAll();
                        }]
                    }
                })

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
        }])
```

_home.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
            ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()"
          style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Title"
                   ng-model="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Link"
                   ng-model="link">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</script>
```

mainCtrl.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
    //Main Controller
    .controller('MainCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        'posts',

        function($scope, posts){
            $scope.posts = posts.posts;
            $scope.addPost = function(){
                if(!$scope.title  || $scope.title == '') { return; }
                posts.create({
                    title: $scope.title,
                    link: $scope.link
                });
                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.link = '';
            };
            $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
                post.upvotes += 1;
            };

        }])
```

If you need any more information then this please let me know. Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: no. This is what has kept my hands tied. All the files are loaded and no erros.

Comment: just posted the page screenshot with the network inspection

Comment: Can you please post the console log screenshot? It's more meaninful for javascript than the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just remove script tags from your templates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but in the tutorial link you posted they have the templates defined as:

```
templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
```

and

```
templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
```

Comment: I checked on that. In fact this is the disposition of the directories recommended in the tutotorial. I had it before like that but due to several changes trying to find the problem I ended up creating the directory templates. However, I made the change to the state you said and the problem persists. One thing I noticed  by just adding some text in the ui-view tag, once I refresh the page that content flashes  on the screen and then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help, but you can try changing your href="#/posts/{{$index}}" to ui-sref="posts({ id: $index })""
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Also, here is a template you can buy for cheap that uses ui-router and Rails
https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/angle-bootstrap-admin-app-angularjs-WB04HF123

Answer (score -2):

check the braces, not closed properly in resolve. It should be 
        
               `resolve: {
                         postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                            return posts.getAll();
                        ]}`